# Is it possible to use 'using' to declare reference to 3 integers type alias?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, reference, declaration

I have been given an exercise where I need to use a type alias for a 'reference to 3 integers'. Although I found success using `typedef` I'm not able to replicate it by `using` introduced by `c++11`.

**Code :**

`typedef int (& int_ref)[3]; \\success`

`using int_ref2 =  (int &) [3]; \\error`

*Should I then just use something like ...*

`using int_ref2 = int [3];`

`int_ref2 & iruvar ...`

Comment: It's the same thing without the identifier: `using int_ref2 = int (&)[3]`

Comment: Just remember that every time you obscure your code like this it increases the difficulty to read and debug the code; especially for other people who have to maintain it.  The larger the project the worse it becomes.

Comment: IMO you should avoid things like references or pointers in type-aliases, it will make code harder to read and understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare these two declarations

```
typedef int (& int_ref)[3]; \\success

using int_ref2 =  (int &) [3]; \\error
```

As you can see there is a difference: in the second declaration type specifier `int` is inside the parentheses.

So place it outside the parentheses

```
using int_ref2 =  int( & )[3];
```

All you need is to move the type name used in the typedef outside the parentheses to the left side relative to the equation sign.

The advantage of using the using declaration is that it has more strict and clear style.

Compare it for example with the following typedef declaration

```
int typedef (& int_ref)[3];
```

that is also a valid declaration.:)

Comment: For my sanity, also remove the extra white space in the `( &)`!

Comment: @Yakk I added a space.:)